# ultrawide monitor 21:9 lack of resolution 2560x1080

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, resolution

I have a pc with dual boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 (gnome 3.28.4) and Windows 10 and an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series card. My monitor LG 29WK500-P has a native resolution of 2560x1080. Windows detect it normally and everything works fine but Ubuntu is not found 2560x1080 in the list of resolutions and max resolution which I can set in ubuntu is 1920x1080.

I tried add manually resolution (https://www.leowkahman.com/2019/02/06/ultrawide-monitor-on-linux/) by *cvt* and *xrandr* commands.

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm
   1920x1080     50.00    59.99*   59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00    59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94
```

I tied with frequencies from 56 till 75 but mostly after set *xrandr output* screen was black, how ever when tried cvt with values 72,73,74,75 it showed screen similar like on screen

[image: screen]

EDIT:
As harrymc asked I add what I tried and results (I did it today and yesterday and I had to several times restart pc so part can reoccure):

```
gtf 2560 1080 50 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST" 188.60  2560 2704 2976 3392  1080 1081 1084 1112  -HSync +Vsync
gtf 2560 1080 55 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST" 209.98  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1081 1084 1115  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --newmode "TEST2" 209.98  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1081 1084 1115  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST2"
gtf 2560 1080 60 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST3" 230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST3"
gtf 2560 1080 65 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST4" 251.82  2560 2728 3008 3456  1080 1081 1084 1121  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST4"
gtf 2560 1080 70 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST5" 273.18  2560 2736 3016 3472  1080 1081 1084 1124  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST5"
gtf 2560 1080 75 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST6" 295.08  2560 2744 3024 3488  1080 1081 1084 1128  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST6"
gtf 2560 1080 71 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "TEST7" 277.33  2560 2736 3016 3472  1080 1081 1084 1125  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST7"
gtf 2560 1080 69 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "TEST8" 269.27  2560 2736 3016 3472  1080 1081 1084 1124  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST8"
gtf 2560 1080 80 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST9" 315.59  2560 2744 3024 3488  1080 1081 1084 1131  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST9"
gtf 2560 1080 66 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST" 255.92  2560 2728 3008 3456  1080 1081 1084 1122  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST"
gtf 2560 1080 67 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST2"
xrandr --newmode "TEST2" 259.80  2560 2728 3008 3456  1080 1081 1084 1122  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST2"
gtf 2560 1080 68 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "TEST3"  263.91  2560 2728 3008 3456  1080 1081 1084 1123  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "TEST3"
cvt 2560 1080 55 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_55.00"  209.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1117 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_55.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_55.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr
cvt 2560 1080 56 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_56.00"  213.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1118 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_56.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_56.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 57 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_57.00"  218.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1119 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_57.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 58 <- black screen
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_58.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_58.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 59 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_59.00"  226.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_59.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_59.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 60 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 61 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_61.00"  235.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1121 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_61.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_61.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 62 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_62.00"  239.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1122 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_62.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_62.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr
cvt 2560 1080 63 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_63.00"  243.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1122 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_63.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_63.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 64 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_64.00"  247.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1123 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_64.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_64.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 65 <- black screen
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_65.00
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_65.00"  251.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1124 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_65.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 66 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_66.00"  256.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1124 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_66.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_66.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 67 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_67.00"  260.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1125 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_67.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 68 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_68.00"  264.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1126 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 69 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_69.00"  268.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1126 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_69.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 69.50 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_69.50"  270.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1127 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_69.50
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 70 <- black screen
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_70.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 70.50 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_70.50"  274.50  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1127 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_70.50
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 71 <- black screen
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_71.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 72 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_72.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 72.10
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_72.10
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 71.99
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_71.9
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_71.99
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 73 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode"2560x1080_73.00"  285.75  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_73.00"  285.75  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 74 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 75  <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_75.00"  294.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1130 -hsync +vsync.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 71.90 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_71.90"  281.25  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1128 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_71.90
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_71.90
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 73.50 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_73.50"  288.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_73.50
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_73.50
cvt 2560 1080 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_71.00"  276.50  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1128 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_71.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_71.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 72 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_72.00"  281.75  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1128 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_72.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_72.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 73 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_73.00"  285.75  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_73.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_73.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_72.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_71.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 74 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_74.00"  290.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_74.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_74.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 75 <- similar like on photo
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_75.00"  294.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1130 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_75.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 76 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_76.00"  298.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1131 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_76.00
cvt 2560 1080 72.90 
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_72.90"  285.50  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_72.90
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_72.90
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 72.80
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_72.80"  285.00  2560 2744 3016 3472  1080 1083 1093 1129 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_72.80
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_72.80
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr
gtf 2560 1080 60 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
xrandr
cvt 2560 1080 50 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_50.00"  188.75  2560 2712 2976 3392  1080 1083 1093 1114 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_50.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_50.00
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.99*
cvt 2560 1080 51 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_51.00"  192.75  2560 2712 2976 3392  1080 1083 1093 1115 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_51.00
cvt 2560 1080 52 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_52.00"  196.50  2560 2712 2976 3392  1080 1083 1093 1115 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_52.00
cvt 2560 1080 53 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_53.00"  201.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1116 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_53.00
cvt 2560 1080 53 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 54 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_54.00"  205.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1117 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_54.00
cvt 2560 1080 55 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_55.00"  209.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1117 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_55.00
cvt 2560 1080 56 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_56.00"  213.25  2560 2720 2984 3408  1080 1083 1093 1118 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_56.00
cvt 2560 1080 57 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_57.00"  218.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1119 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_57.00
cvt 2560 1080 58 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_58.00"  222.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1119 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_58.00
cvt 2560 1080 59 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_59.00"  226.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_59.00
cvt 2560 1080 60 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_60.00"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_60.00_"  230.00  2560 2720 2992 3424  1080 1083 1093 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_60.00_
cvt 2560 1080 61 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_61.00"  235.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1121 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_61.00
cvt 2560 1080 62 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_62.00"  239.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1122 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_62.00
cvt 2560 1080 63 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_63.00"  243.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1122 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_63.00
cvt 2560 1080 64 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 65 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 66 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 67 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 68 <- black screen
cvt 2560 1080 69 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_64.00"  247.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1123 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_65.00"  251.00  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1083 1093 1124 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_66.00"  256.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1124 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_67.00"  260.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1125 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_68.00"  264.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1126 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_69.00"  268.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1126 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_65.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_66.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_67.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_68.00
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_69.00
cvt 2560 1080 70 <- black screen
xrandr --newmode  "2560x1080_70.00"  272.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1127 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_70.00
```

EDIT 2: 
I removed my Radeon from PC and connected to integrated graphics card when Ubuntu started then it had resolution 2560x1080 (but then nothing is showed during boot process, just when showed ubuntu login screen). I used command:

```
xvidtune -show
```

Which showed used modeline and next I installed radeon card and tried use this modeline. Unfortunately after apply it doesn't works and  shows black screen on monitor :(

EDIT 3:
I installed also the newest version of Ubuntu 19.10 (I had free space on my disk) but there also no detect resolution 2560x1080.

Answer (score 3):

You may create the new mode resolution using `xrandr` and `gtf`.

To get the mode information :

```
gtf 2560 1080 60
```

You might get something like :

```
# 2560x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 230.76 MHz
  Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

Then create the new mode using xrandr with the above data :

```
 xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60" 230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
```

To add the mode to `HDMI-0`:

```
xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_60
```

Finally to apply the new mode :

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 2560x1080_60
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125783/219-2560x1080-with-amd-card)

Comment: I tried this method and it doesn't works.

Comment: Could you add to the post what you tried and its results.

Comment: I updated post and added commands which I tried and results.

Comment: This might be a driver problem. The latest driver seems to be [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-20). Better verify if that version is later than yours.

Comment: How I can check version of drivers? However as I see these drivers aren't for my Radeon HD 6700 card

Comment: This worked for Mint hosted in proxmox streamed over SPICE and nomachine. What I have to ask is why isn't the 21:9 resolution available or detected by default?

Comment: @gurpal2000: Probably this resolution is not listed in the EDID that's returned by the monitor's firmware.

Comment: @harrymc - well windows/linux straight onto the machine/monitor works fine. It's only when i use the proxmox vga or spice driver. So I guess question is for those forums?

Answer (score 2):

Just building up on @harrymc 's answer:

Check your HDMI version (before using `gtf`) by comparing the release date of your board and those of the HDMI versions, just to discard the possibility of having an old version which does not support such resolution with those refresh rates.

In my case, probably 1.4b, I lost a lot of time messing with outdated drivers and different combinations of modelines, just to get it working with 30Hz (best I could get with my old video card)

Comment: THIS! I made a manual binary search and found that my video card can't handle more than 44.20Hz

Answer (score 0):

With some small changes @harrymc 's answer worked for me. One step to add at the start is to run `xrandr --listactivemonitors`- doing so showed that my external monitor was named `HDMI-1` not `HDMI-0`. I replaced the name in the last two commands of the instructions and everything works.

Also - like @L_Arm suggests - check your HDMI version. If that can't handle the resolution/refresh rate try plugging the monitor into the DisplayPort if your machine has one.

Answer (score -1):

I follow harrymc and i got it! I just make some changes as below

1. `$ gtf 2560 1080 60`
2. My output is `# 2560x1080 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 67.08 kHz; pclk: 230.76 MHz Modeline "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync`
3. `$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_60.00"  230.76  2560 2728 3000 3440  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync`
4. `$ xrandr --listmonitors`
5. My output is
   `Monitors: 1 0: +*Virtual1 2560/677x1080/286+0+0  Virtual1`
6. `$ xrandr --addmode Virtual1 2560x1080_60`
7. After that, you can right click in your home screen, display settings and now you can see the resolution 2560x1080